# Почему не срабатывает условие при проверке переменной на NaN?

Tags: javascript

```
let number = prompt("Введите любое число");
console.log(number*1); //если это не число, то будет NaN
if (number*1 == NaN) {
  alert("Это не число!"); //не срабатывает, когда number*1 - это NaN
}
```

Comment: почему вы решили что она не срабатывает ?

Comment: `NaN` не равно и не идентично другому `NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN` не равно и не идентично другому `NaN`!

```js
let number = prompt("Введите любое число");
if (isNaN(+number)) {
  alert("Это не число!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сравнение `NaN` с чем угодно (в том числе и с `NaN`) возвращает `false`.

```
if (isNaN(number*1)) {
```

```js
var a = NaN;
console.log(a == NaN);
console.log(isNaN(a));
```